# A stub that returns a stub

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

Let's say you have code that returns an object containing pre-programmed functions, which you use like this:

```
someFunction(/* pass in data */)
  .post(/* some data */)  //Returned post function is pre-programmed to send a POST request to the right URL
  .then(function() {
    //do something
  });
```

How can I unit test this using [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/)?

To direct what a function returns, you need to use a stub:

```
var mockService = sinon.stub();
mockService.returns(/* some return value */);
```

But let's say I want to verify that `someFunction` was called with the right arguments, in addition to verifying that the returned post function was called with the right arguments. I would need a stub to return a stub:

```
mockService.returns({
  post: sinon.stub()
});
```

How can I access `mockService.post` to verify that the right arguments were passed, in this case?

**Bonus Question:** What's the name of this design pattern (returning a function with pre-programmed behavior)? I've seen it used before, but don't know the name of it.

Comment: Regarding the design pattern, perhaps you're thinking of [Curried Functions](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/index.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered, I worked around this like this:

```
var mockServicePost = sinon.stub();
var mockService = sinon.stub();
mockService.returns({
  post: mockServicePost
});
```

But I am interested to know if there's a more elegant solution than this.